# Vim indentation for html files

Tags: indentation

Most of my edits are done in .html files. However, I write a lot of jinja code and css in these html files.

### Problem 1: Jinja Indentation

whenever I have a bloc such as this:

```
{{ my_macro(arg1, arg2, arg3) }}
```

My ideal level of indentation will be:

```
<previous line indents here> 
{{ my_macro(arg1,
            arg2,
            arg3) }}
```

However, right now I am seeing this level of indentation in my vim :

```
<previous line indents here> 
{{ my_macro(arg1,
arg2,
arg3) }}
```

### Problem 2: CSS indentation

I have the following style element:

```
<div parent>
  <style>
  .indent-should-be-here {}
  </style>
```

but in reality I am seeing:

```
<div parent>
  <style>
.indent-on-the-left-most-why {}
  </style>
```

I currently have Vim-Jinja2-Syntax installed. But it only calls the html indent. See .vim/bundle/Vim-Jinja-Syntax/indent/jinja.vim

```
" Vim indent file
" Language: Jinja HTML template
" Maintainer:   Evan Hammer <evan@evanhammer.com>
" Last Change:  2013 Jan 26

" Only load this indent file when no other was loaded.
if exists("b:did_indent")
  finish
endif

" Use HTML formatting rules.
runtime! indent/html.vim
```

Does anyone have a recommendation for me?

Comment: turns out there's html5 plugin

Answer (score -2):

Try using == to auto-indent one line.

Use =G when you're at the top of page, to auto-indent the whole file

Comment: Not what the OP asked. He obviously knows how to make Vim indent, as he provides samples of the result of such an operation; he is asking how to make Vim indent certain files *correctly*.